# Install ActiveDirectory PowerShell module on the AzureAD Connect server

Tags: active-directory, azureadconnect

**Overview**

We have a server dedicated to AzureAD Connect. We're a small organisation (less than 300 staff). I am considering installing the ActiveDirectory PowerShell module ([click here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/?view=windowsserver2019-ps)) on the same server.

**Question(s)**

1. Has anyone here done this before?
2. Did anyone run into issues doing so?
3. Any advice, warnings, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

1. Has anyone here done this before?

Yes

2. Did anyone run into issues doing so?

No

3. Any advice, warnings, etc.?

No